# RAILS bundle install Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been learning rails for a couple of weeks and a couple hours ago `bundle install` just stopped working. This is the error I get:

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\cokl>cd delicikush

C:\Users\cokl\delicikush>rails bundle install --trace
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'bundle' (see --tasks)
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:58:in `[]'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:151:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

C:\Users\cokl\delicikush>
```

My gemfile:
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I don't think I changed anything other than my models and controllers, I don't know what other files I should post so feel free to ask for them.
Thanks for the answer in advance.

Comment: no need for `rails` before `bundle install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `bundle install` to install your gems.

Bundler is just a way to manage your application gems with a `Gemfile`, you can use Bundler for every Ruby application and not just Rails.